# Recursive calls to Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a Firebase Firestore with "Components" as a root collection. Each document (a "Component") in the collection  may have an array called "children", with each item in the array being an "id" of another component, essentially, a one-to-many relationship. Since every child is also a component it may also have its own children and so forth.

### Components Collection

#### Parent

```
1_Parent (document)
│ name: 'Parent'
│ id: '1_Parent'
└─children (array)
   ├─1.1_Child_one
   └─1.2_Child_two
```

#### First Child

```
1.1_Child_one (document)
     name: 'Child One'
     id: '1.1_Child_one'
```

#### Second Child

```
1.2_Child_two (document)
│ name: 'Child Two'
│ id: '1.2_Child_two'
└─children (array)
   ├─1.2.1_Grandchild_one
   └─1.2.2_Grandchild_two
```

#### First Grandchild

```
1.2.1_Grandchild_one (document)
     name: 'Grandchild One'
     id: '1.2.1_Grandchild_one'
```

#### Second Grandchild

```
1.2.2_Grandchild_two (document)
 name: 'Grandchild Two'
 id: '1.2.2_Grandchild_two'
```

In my code, I want to create an object for each component and if it has a children array then each of the id in the array is replaced by a fully fledged object retrieved from Firestore.

The output object tree should look like this

```
1_Parent
│ name: 'Parent'
│ id: '1_Parent'
└─children
   ├─1.1_Child_one
   │    name: 'Child One'
   │    id: '1.1_Child_one'
   └─1.2_Child_two
     │  name: 'Child Two'
     │  id: '1.2_Child_two'
     └─children
        ├─1.2.1_grandhild_one
        │   name: 'Grandchild One'
        │   id: '1.2.1_grandhild_one'
        └─1.2.2_grandhild_two
            name: 'Grandchild Two'
            id: '1.2.2_grandhild_two'
```

The output object as JSON should look like this

```
{
  "name": "Parent",
  "id": "1_Parent",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Child One",
      "id": "1.1_Child_one"
    },
    {
      "name": "Child Two",
      "id": "1.2_Child_two",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Grandchild One",
          "id": "1.2.1_Grandchild_one"
        },
        {
          "name": "Grandchild Two",
          "id": "1.2.2_Grandchild_two"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It is obvious, we need recursion here, but I am at complete loss about how to create a recursive function using RxJS. I would appreciate some tips or example code for allowing to do so.

Note, I am using this in an Angular project and I am using AngularFire to access Firebase-Firestore.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion in RxJS is best tackled with the use of the `expand` operator. You provide it with a projection function that returns an Observable, that, on notification, calls the projection function again with the emitted value. It does this for as long as your inner Observable is not emitting `EMPTY` or `complete`.

While it does that, every notification is also forwarded to the subscribers of `expand`, unlike with a traditional recursion where you'll only get the result at the very end.

From the official docs on `expand`:

> Recursively projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable.

Let's look at your example. Without RxJS, if we had a synchronous datasource that gave us each child of a node (let's call it `getChildById`), the function could look like this:

```
function createFamilyTree(node) {
    node.children = node.childrenIds.map(childId => 
        createFamilyTree(
            getChildById(childId)
        )
    );
    return node;
}
```

Now, we'll translate it to RxJS with the use of the `expand` operator:

```
parentDataSource$.pipe(
    map(parent => ({node: parent})),

    expand(({node}) => // expand is called for every node recursively 
                          (i.e. the parent and each child, then their children and so on)

        !node ? EMPTY : // if there is no node, end the recursion

        from(node.childrenIds) // we'll convert the array of children 
                                  ids to an observable stream

            .pipe(
                mergeMap(childId => getChildById(childId) // and get the child for 
                                                              the given id

                    .pipe(
                        map(child => ({node: child, parent: node}))) // map it, so we have 
                                                                       the reference to the 
                                                                       parent later on
                )
            )
    ),

    // we'll get a bunch of notifications, but only want the "root", 
       that's why we use reduce:

    reduce((acc, {node, parent}) =>
        !parent ?
            node : // if we have no parent, that's the root node and we return it
            parent.children.push(node) && acc // otherwise, we'll add children
    )
);
```

The used operators are explained in detail on the official RxJS documentation page: [from](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from), [expand](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand), [reduce](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce)

**EDIT**: A clean and tested version of the above code can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vzxhqf?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Could you provide a working example with some test data to see how your code, based on use of `expand`, would actually work?

Comment: here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vzxhqf?devtoolsheight=60
I noticed a mistake where I used `map` instead of `switchMap`. This is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you can consider to use `mergeMap` rather than `switchMap`. If you add a delay to `getChildById` function, which is a better simulation in case you need to fetch data from a remote db, than `mergeMap` seems to work better.

Answer (score 3):

You may look at a solution along these lines

```
// simulates an async data fetch from a remote db
function getComponent(id) {
  return of(components.find(comp => comp.id === id)).pipe(delay(10));
}

function expandComp(component: Observable<any>) {
  return component.pipe(
    tap(d => console.log('s', d.name)),
    mergeMap(component => {
      if (component.childrenIds) {
        return concat(
          of(component).pipe(tap(comp => comp['children'] = [])),
          from(component.childrenIds).pipe(
            mergeMap(childId => expandComp(getComponent(childId)))
          )
        )
        .pipe(
          reduce((parent: any, child) => {
            parent.children.push(child);
            return parent;
          })
        )
      } 
      else {
        return of(component);
      }
    })
  )
}
.subscribe(d => // do stuff, e.g. console.log(JSON.stringify(d, null, 3)))
```

I have tested the above code with the following test data

```
const componentIds: Array<string> = [
  '1',
  '1.1.2'
]
const components: Array<any> = [
  {id: '1', name: 'one', childrenIds: ['1.1', '1.2']},
  {id: '1.1', name: 'one.one', childrenIds: ['1.1.1', '1.1.2']},
  {id: '1.2', name: 'one.two'},
  {id: '1.1.1', name: 'one.one.one'},
  {id: '1.1.2', name: 'one.one.two', childrenIds: ['1.1.2.1', '1.1.2.2', '1.1.2.3']},
  {id: '1.1.2.1', name: 'one.one.two.one'},
  {id: '1.1.2.2', name: 'one.one.two.two'},
  {id: '1.1.2.3', name: 'one.one.two.three'},
]
```

The basic idea is to call recursively the `expandComp` function, while the looping along the *children* of each component is obtained using the `from` function provided by RxJS.

The grouping of the *children* within the *parent* component is provided using the `reduce` operator of RxJS, used within `expandComp` function.

I have tried initially to look at the `expand` operator of RxJS, but I was not able to find a solution using it. The solution proposed by @ggradnig leverages `expand`.