# Nested ApiCalls with Angular HttpClient and RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

So, I have server which on request returns array of objects

Example:

```
[
  {
   id: 1
   name: name1
  },
  {
   id: 2
   name: name2
  }
]
```

Array can have infinite elements;

After that I have to send new requests for each element in array with id of response.

example:

```
https://localhost/api/parent/${id}/child
```

response:

```
[
  {
   childId: 1
   name: name1
  },
  {
   childId: 2
   name: name2
  },
  {
   childId: 3
   name: name3
  }
]
```

And after that I have to send new requests for each response of new requests

example:

```
https://localhost/api/parent/${id}/child/${childId}/grandChild
```

response:

```
[
  {
   grandChildId: 1
   name: name1
  },
  {
   grandChildId: 2
   name: name2
  },
  {
   grandChildId: 3
   name: name3
  }
]
```

and response is similiar like others

and after that i have to organize data to look like this

```
[
  {
   id: 1
   name: name1
   children: [
            {
              childId: 1
              name: name1,
              grandChildren: [
                            {
                             grandChildId: 1
                             name: name1
                            },
                            {
                             grandChildId: 2
                             name: name2
                            },
                            {
                             grandChildId: 3
                             name: name3
                            }
                            ]
            },
            {
             childId: 2
             name: name2
            },
            {
            childId: 3
            name: name3
            }
        ]
  },
  {
   id: 2
   name: name2
  }
]
```

Each parent has array of children and each child has array of grandChildren.

This was my try but if i try in component to do parents.forEach(parent => console.log(parent.childern)) it is undefined

```
getData() {

return this.http.get<Parent[]>(baseUrl + 'parent', {withCredentials: true}).pipe(
      map(parents => {
        parents.forEach(parent => {
          this.getChildren(parent).subscribe(Children => {
            parent.Children = Children;
            parent.Children.forEach(Children => {
              this.getGrandChildren(Children).subscribe(grandChild => {
                Children.grandChildren = grandChild;
              });
            });
          });
        });
      return parents;
      })
        );
```

}

```
 getChildren(parent: Parent): Observable<Child[]> {
  return this.http.get<Children[]>(baseUrl + `parent/${parent.id}/children`, {withCredentials: true});
```

}

```
 getGrandChildren(child: Child): Observable<GrandChild[]> {
return this.http.get<GrandChild[]>(baseUrl + `children/${child.id}/GrandChildren`, {withCredentials: true});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your problem, it seems to be of a recursive nature.

**Parent**, **Child**, **GrandChild** are all similar and look like a flat representation of nodes and leafs of a tree. If this is the case, you may look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129852/recursive-calls-to-firestore/53153891#53153891) for some details on how to do recursive processing with RxJS.

Remaining strictly to the way you represented your problem, at least up to my understanding, here is a way to solve it

```
getParents()
.pipe(
  switchMap(parents => from(parents)),
  mergeMap(parent => getChildren(parent)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(children => from(children)),
      mergeMap(child => getGrandChildren(child)
        .pipe(
          tap(grandChildren => child.grandChildren = grandChildren),
          map(() => child)
        )
      ),
      toArray(),
      tap(children => parent.children = children),
      map(() => parent)
    ), 1  // cuncurrency set to 1 to guarantee same order
  ),
)
.subscribe(d => console.log(JSON.stringify(d, null, 2)))
```

I have tested it with the following simulation data and functions

```
const parents = [
  {id: 1, name: 'name1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'name2'},
];
const children = [
  {childId: 1, name: 'name1'},
  {childId: 2, name: 'name2'},
  {childId: 3, name: 'name3'},
];
const grandChildren = [
  {grandChildId: 1, name: 'name1'},
  {grandChildId: 2, name: 'name2'},
  {grandChildId: 3, name: 'name3'},
];

function getParents(): Observable<Parent[]> {
  return of(parents).pipe(delay(10));
}
function getChildren(parent: Parent): Observable<Child[]> {
  return (parent.id === 1 ? of(children) : of([])).pipe(
    delay(100)
  );
}
function getGrandChildren(child: Child): Observable<GrandChild[]> {
  return (child.childId === 1 ? of(grandChildren) : of([])).pipe(delay(1000));
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! It solved my problem. One small problem, data doesn't come in right order, but i can sort that!

Comment: I does not come in the right order since I have put some delays to make it more realistic, in case you have to fetch those data from a remote system via an async API. You can solve the problem substituting the first `mergeMap` with `concatMap` or adding 1 as `concurrency` parameter again in the first `mergeMap`. I have updated my response with the second option.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out ishould use concatMap, had to add toArray() at end too, cause it was returning single object. Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 getRoot() {
    return this.http.get<Parent[]>(baseUrl + 'parent', {withCredentials: true}).pipe(
      switchMap(items => forkJoin(items.map(i => this.getChild(i))))
    )
  }

  getChild(parent) {
    return this.http.get<Children[]>(baseUrl + `parent/${parent.id}/children`, {withCredentials: true}).pipe(
      switchMap(items => forkJoin(items.map(i => this.getGrandChild(i)))),
      map(resp => (parent.children = resp, parent))
    );

  }

  getGrandChild(parent) {
    return this.http.get<GrandChild[]>(baseUrl + `children/${child.id}/GrandChildren`, {withCredentials: true}).pipe(
      map(resp => (parent.grandChildren = resp, parent))
    )
  }
```

The uses `items.map` to convert the array of results into an array of requests for the relevant children.

It then uses `forkJoin`to join all of those requests into 1 Observable

It then uses `switchMap` to make the requests, and `map` to add the children onto the response.

**[Here is a Stackblitz to demonstrate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2trlb)**

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that you confuse uppercase and lowercase? Use Conventions to be able to recognize something.

Well try **parent.children**

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` will return `Observable<any>` data so you cannot just read the data in using `map`operator and you are trying to loop through the `Observable<any>`

To get the data from this function - `this.getData()` you need to access this from your component class like `this.getData().subscribe((res) => {console.log(res)})` now you can see the data in the console

So now loop through the array and call the another service function - make sure you have separate function for all the `parent` `children` and `grandChildren` or else have a common `http.get()` function and pass down the URL to get the data - it is not a best way to have nested `HttpClient` calls

Hope you understood - happy coding